# Calculating the percentages of net profit over cost

Tags: real-analysis, percentages

I am stuck at a couple of percentage questions.

A merchant sells an item at a 20% discount. But still makes a profit of 20% of the COST. What percentage of the cost would the Gross profit on the item have been if it had been sold without the discount.

At a special sale, 5 tickets can be purchased for the price of 3 tickets. If 5 tickets are purchased at this rate, the mount saved will be what percent of the original price of the 5 tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage profit P = $\frac{(SP-C)}{C}$

P = $\frac{(0.8SP-C)}{C} = .2$

$.8SP = 1.2C$

$ SP = \frac{1.2}{.8}C = 1.5C$

Without Discount

P = $\frac{(1.5C-C)}{C} = .5 = 50$%

Part 2:

Original Price = P

Amount spent on buying 5 tickets on sale $= 3*P$

Amount spent on one ticket $= \frac{3P}{5}$

Amount spent on one ticket without sale$ = P$

Savings on one ticket $= P-\frac{3P}{5}=\frac{2P}{5}$

Savings on 5 tickets as a percentage of original price $= \dfrac{\frac{2P}{5}.\times 5}{5P}$

Savings on 5 tickets $= 40$%

Answer (score 1):

Let the marked price (on which discount is offered) be x. Selling price = 100% x - 20% x = 80% x = 0.8 x.

Now, selling price = cost price + 20% of cost price.

Selling price = 120/100 * cost price = 1.2 cost price

0.8 x = 1.2 * Cost price

Cost price = 0.8/1.2 x = 2/3 x

Without discount, Selling price = marked price = x.

Profit = selling price - cost price = x - 2/3 x = 1/3 x.

Let gross profit be y% of cost price.

Therefore, (y/100) * 2/3 x = 1/3 x

y/100 = (1/3) * x * (3/2) * (1/x)

y/100 = 1/2

y = 50

Therefore, the profit would have been 50% of the cost without discount.

PROBLEM 2:

Let x be the original cost of each ticket.
Price of 5 tickets = 5x

Under the special sale, Price of 5 tickets = Original price of 3 tickets = 3x

Amount saved = 5x - 3x = 2x

Let amount saved be y% of original price of 5 tickets.

therefore, y/100 * (Original price of 5 tickets) = Amount saved.

y/100 * 5x = 2x

Dividing both sides by x

y/100 * 5 = 2

y/20 = 2

y = 40

Therefore, the amount saved will be 40 percent of the original price of the 5 tickets.